# resteasy, how to initialize @Context UriInfo parameter for use in proxy client call?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jax-rs, resteasy

My resteasy endpoint interface is declared like this:

```
@Path("/entity")
public interface EntitySearchEndpoint {
...
    @GET
    @Path("/search")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response search(@Context UriInfo ui);
...
}
```

Now I created proxy client using the interface

```
ResteasyClient reClient = new ResteasyClientBuilder().build();
ResteasyWebTarget webTarget = reClient.target(URI.create("http://example.com"));
EntitySearchEndpoint entitySearchEndpoint = ncspAPIWebTarget.proxy(EntitySearchEndpoint.class);
```

Now I am able to call service using

```
UriInfo ui = ???
Response response = entitySearchEndpoint.search(ui);
```

My question is how to create instance of UriInfo to contain only required query-parameters?
Probably using `@Context UriInfo` as parameter is not correct, what is correct way?
QueryParam names list is not restricted, any name is allowed...

Answer (score 1):

If I understood what you want correctly, your API could look something like this:

```
@Path("/entity")
public interface EntitySearchEndpoint {
...
    @GET
    @Path("/search/{searchQuery}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response search(@PathParam("searchQuery") String searchQuery);
...
}
```

and your client would just call it with a string:

```
Response response = entitySearchEndpoint.search("test string");
```

Comment: Thank you Randy, I finally found solution now I don't even remember it but, I'll try to write it here later. The point is that search parameters was in query parametrs, means after question mark '?paam1=value1&param2=value2&.....'

Comment: I see, then you're probably using @QueryParam. I wouldn't use UriInfo (which you would not pass as a parameter like that) because someone looking at your api code would not realize it has inputs. QueryParam is much clearer.

Comment: Yeah, but count of parameters can vary and its names can vary as well...